# Automate Kubernetes Cluster creation in vSphere

Tags: docker, kubernetes, vsphere

I want a script/tool/plugin that can be used to automate kubernetes cluster creation in vSphere. I want to create 3 virtual machines, one master and two worker nodes. Is there a way that this creation can be automated?
Or is there a way where I won't need to configure every vm individually?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to automate vSphrere cluster creation/managing is to use [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/).

There is a module called [Terraform vSphere Module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Terraform-VMWare-Modules/vm/vsphere/latest) - it contains  most of the advance features that are available in the resource [vsphere_virtual_machine](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine)

[Terraform vSphere Module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Terraform-VMWare-Modules/vm/vsphere/latest):

> This Terraform module deploys single or multiple virtual machines of
> type (Linux/Windows) with following features:
>
> - Ability to specify Linux or Windows VM customization.
> - Ability to add multiple network cards for the VM Ability to assign tags and custom variables.
> - Ability to configure advance features for the vm.
> - Ability to deploy either a datastore or a datastore cluster. Add extra data
>   disk (up to 15) to the VM. Different datastores for data disks
>   (datastore_id). Different scsi_controllers per disk, including data
>   disks.
> - Ability to define depend on using variable vm_depends_on & tag_depends_on

> Note: For module to work it needs number of required
> variables corresponding to an existing resources in vSphere. Please
> refer to variable section for the list of required variables.

Example:

```
# Configure the VMware vSphere Provider
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = "fill"
  password       = "fill"
  vsphere_server = "fill" 

  # if you have a self-signed cert
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

# Deploy 2 linux VMs
module "example-server-linuxvm" {
  source        = "Terraform-VMWare-Modules/vm/vsphere"
  version       = "X.X.X"
  vmtemp        = "VM Template Name (Should Alrerady exist)"
  instances     = 2
  vmname        = "example-server-linux"
  vmrp          = "esxi/Resources - or name of a resource pool"
  network = {
    "Name of the Port Group in vSphere" = ["10.13.113.2", "10.13.113.3"] # To use DHCP create Empty list ["",""]
  }
  vmgateway         = "10.13.113.1"
  dc        = "Datacenter"
  datastore = "Data Store name(use ds_cluster for datastore cluster)"
}
```

More information and examples:

**1.** [Using Infrastructure as Code to Automate VMware Deployments](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/using-infrastructure-as-code-to-automate-vmware-deployments)

**2.** [Building vSphere virtual machines with Terraform](https://buildvirtual.net/building-vsphere-virtual-machines-with-terraform/)

**3.** [How to Install Terraform for Use with vSphere](https://www.altaro.com/vmware/install-terraform-vsphere/)

**4.** [vsphere_virtual_machine terraform module](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine)

---

You can also look into [Hashicorp Packer](https://www.packer.io/) side to use it in spike with Terraform.

Packer is:

> A free open-source tool to create images or VMs in multiple platforms
> (Azure, AWS, Google Cloud, VMware, OpenShift, etc.), perfect to create
> templates, build the same image in multiple environments or demos

Your preliminary plan would be:

```
1. Create VM templates with packer (You are here)
2. Create nodes with terraform
3. Create clusters with kubeadm
```

More information here:

- [Deploying VMware vSphere Virtual Machines with Packer & Terraform](https://gmusumeci.medium.com/deploying-vmware-vsphere-virtual-machines-with-packer-terraform-d0211f72b7f5)
- [Kubernetes on Vsphere (Packer - Part 1)](https://medium.com/kuranda-labs-engineering/kubernetes-on-vsphere-packer-part-1-b2ed5071e2b5)
- [Kubernetes on Vsphere (Terraform — Part 2)](https://medium.com/kuranda-labs-engineering/kubernetes-on-vsphere-terraform-part-2-64bac93116e9)